# Change QGIS language instalated in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis

I'm begginer Ubuntu 16.04. I installed QGIS following steps I found in youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEAdKmToULo). QGIS was installed in Portuguese. I want change QGIS language to English and if possible, I want be able to change QGIS language by clicks. It is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Options ...` and select `Locale` tab. On this tab override default language.

[image]

Also see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#locale-menu)